# How are static variables initialized, and what happens when modify them?

Tags: c++, static

I ran into a interesting issue today.  Check out this pseudo-code:

```
void Loop()
{
   static int x = 1;
   printf("%d", x);
   x++;
}

void main(void)
{
    while(true)
    {
       Loop();
    }
}
```

Even though x is static, why doesn't this code just print "1" every time?  I am reinitializing x to 1 on every iteration before I print it.  But for whatever reason, x increments as expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The initialization of a static variable only happens the first time.  After that, the instance is shared across all calls to the function.

Answer (score 3):

> I am reinitializing x to 1 on every iteration

No, you're not: you're initializing it to 1, but it only gets initialized once.

Answer (score 1):

`static` doesn't mean `const`.

From MSDN:

> **When modifying a variable, the static
>   keyword specifies that the variable
>   has static duration (it is allocated
>   when the program begins and
>   deallocated when the program ends)** and
>   initializes it to 0 unless another
>   value is specified. When modifying a
>   variable or function at file scope,
>   the static keyword specifies that the
>   variable or function has internal
>   linkage (its name is not visible from
>   outside the file in which it is
>   declared).
>
> A variable declared static in a
>   function retains its state between
>   calls to that function.
>
> When modifying a data member in a
>   class declaration, the static keyword
>   specifies that one copy of the member
>   is shared by all instances of the
>   class. When modifying a member
>   function in a class declaration, the
>   static keyword specifies that the
>   function accesses only static members.

**The value of static is retained between each function call**, so for example (from MSDN again):

```
// static1.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void showstat( int curr ) {
   static int nStatic;    // Value of nStatic is retained
                          // between each function call
   nStatic += curr;
   cout << "nStatic is " << nStatic << endl;
}

int main() {
   for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
      showstat( i );
}
```

In your example, x will increment as expected because the value is **retained**.

Answer (score 1):

static in this context means that value should be retained between calls to the function. the initialization is done only once.